# How can I make "vue build" spit out non-optimized JS files?

Tags: flask, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to write a single-page web UI using Flask (and Flask-RESTful) for a REST back-end, and Vue.js for the front-end. The problem is, I'm having a hard time using the two together during development.

I can build Vue components using `vue build --prod ...` to obtain a JS file that I can serve as a static file using Flask's web server. This file, however, is optimized for production. Without `--prod`, `vue build` starts a web server directly, which means that if I start `flask run`, JS code is served from a different port than my REST backend, which makes it impossible to use (same origin policy).

So my question is: How can I use Flask and Vue.js together during development?
 How can I make `vue build` spit out *non-optimized* JS files that Flask can serve?

Answer (score 0):

Build in development mode:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode development
```